# How to view the Home/Library file on an external drive?

Tags: macos, finder, external-disk, library

Im running OSX 10.13.6 and I have an external drive in an enclosure that was originally an internal drive of my previous computer running 10.12.

I need to retrieve a file from the /Library external drive, so i go to `/Volumes/External Drive/Users/Sam/` but /Library folder. Any ideas ?

Normally i would just to finder > Go and hit the option key, but this only works for a locally Home/Library not a remote Home/Library.

Comment: How about `/Volumes/External_Drive_Name/Users/Sam/Library/`?

Answer (score 1):

When looking at the home folder where the Library folder would be, toggle ‘Show hidden files’ with <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> then the Library folder (and other hidden files) will be shown.